# jquery style to an asp:button inside a repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net, repeater

this is a little bit difficult question

I have  asp:button ,inside a repeater

```
<asp:button id="tdb1" commandname="update" text=update runat=server ></asp:button>
```

under this button there is a  jquery line script, that determine the classes of the button.

like this:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

   $("#<%=tdb1.ClientID%>").button({icons:{primary:"ui-icon-refresh"}}).addClass("ui-priority-secondary").parent().removeClass("tdbLink");
                                            </script>
```

I am getting error from the compailer : Name 'tdb1' is not declared.

if I change the button to regular button(not asp)the jquery works just fine ,but then I can't capture the event of the button, on server side.

What can I do?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I've learned using .NET is that you're better of using class names for everything. Using IDs will drive you mad because .NET wants to own them all.

Comment: it seem that the text attribute in the asp:button is corrupt the style!what can i do?

Comment: yes it quote ,but still the style is corrupt ,I mean, the text seem to cover the orignal styles

Comment: Without seeing the OUTPUT (not your server code) with your CSS I really can't tell what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the code `tdb1.ClientID` is looking for a `tdb1` control outside of your repeater.

As @Diodeus has stated, you are best to use classes with ASP.NET jQuery like:

```
<asp:button class='<%#String.Format("tdb_{0}", Container.ItemIndex)%>' id="tdb1" commandname="update" text="update" runat="server"></asp:button>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('<%#String.Format(".tdb_{0}", Container.ItemIndex)%>').button({icons:{primary:"ui-icon-refresh"}}).addClass("ui-priority-secondary").parent().removeClass("tdbLink");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks guys,it seem that the runat="server" is corrupt the style,why is that?

Comment: Could be your syntax. Try putting " around the values. See edit to my answer

Comment: no it not the syntax,i check it  and the text attribute in the asp:button is corrupt the style!what can i do?in html button the text is outside the label so the style is ok but in asp:button the text is part of the label

Comment: the text seem to cover the orignal styles

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the button because it's nested in the repeater. You could try setting the style in the code behind in ItemDataBound, or you could possibly leverage the client onload event of the button.

Comment: text attribute in the asp:button is corrupt the style!what can i do?in html button the text is outside the label so the style is ok, but in asp:button the text is part of the label

and the text seem to cover the orignal styles

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access all buttons, try:

```
<asp:button CssClass="foo" ... />
```

And then

```
$('#repeaterId .foo').button(...).addClass(...); // etc.
```

Comment: text attribute in the asp:button is corrupt the style!what can i do?in html button the text is outside the label so the style is ok, but in asp:button the text is part of the label
and the text seem to cover the orignal styles